# cmake - find_library cannot find library?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to get `OpenEXR` to work in Visual Studio 2015.

The `OpenEXR` is successfully installed and the installation path is

```
C:\Program Files\openexr\
```

where there are two subdirectories: `IlmBase` and `openexr`.

In `FindOpenEXR.cmake`:

```
    FIND_PATH(OPENEXR_INCLUDE_DIR ImfRgbaFile.h PATH_SUFFIXES OpenEXR PATHS $ENV{OPENEXR_PATH}/include $ENV{CPATH})
    FIND_LIBRARY(OPENEXR_HALF_LIBRARY NAMES Half PATHS $ENV{OPENEXR_PATH}/lib $ENV{LIBRARY_PATH})
    FIND_LIBRARY(OPENEXR_IEX_LIBRARY NAMES Iex PATHS $ENV{OPENEXR_PATH}/lib $ENV{LIBRARY_PATH})
    FIND_LIBRARY(OPENEXR_IMATH_LIBRARY NAMES Imath PATHS $ENV{OPENEXR_PATH}/lib $ENV{LIBRARY_PATH})
    FIND_LIBRARY(OPENEXR_ILMIMF_LIBRARY NAMES IlmImf PATHS $ENV{OPENEXR_PATH}/lib $ENV{LIBRARY_PATH})
    FIND_LIBRARY(OPENEXR_ILMTHREAD_LIBRARY NAMES IlmThread PATHS $ENV{OPENEXR_PATH}/lib $ENV{LIBRARY_PATH})
```

So I create an environment variable named `OPENEXR_PATH` and its value is

```
C:\Program Files\openexr\IlmBase;C:\Program Files\openexr\openexr;
```

Under `C:\Program Files\openexr\IlmBase\lib`, there are `Half.lib`, `Iex-2_2.lib`,  `IexMath-2_2.lib`, `IlmThread-2_2.lib` and `Imath-2_2.lib`, as well as the corresponding `.dll` file.

Under `C:\Program Files\openexr\openexr\lib`, there are `IlmImf-2_2.lib` and `IlmImfUtil-2_2.lib` and `.dll`.

I don't know why cmake cannot find these libraries?

Does the version number of `.lib` file matter? And the `/` and `\` in path?

Comment: `$ENV{OPENEXR_PATH}/lib` is expanded wronly if *OPENEXR_PATH* variable contains *list* of paths. [Also, in CMake find scripts `<program>_PATH` usually means **single directory**.] With given `FindOpenEXR.cmake` you may set *LIBRARY_PATH* environment variable to the list of paths.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Hi, this is where I'm confused. I think OpenEXR should be independent, like what you said, in a single directory. But some of the libraries, e.g. the `HALF` library, is in `IlmBase` directory. Since I'm not quite familiar with cmake, I was wondering if it is the way I install OpenEXR that is wrong?

Comment: `I was wondering if it is the way I install OpenEXR that is wrong?` - I am not familiar with OpenEXR, but according to `FindOpenEXR.cmake` its components are expected to be installed into **the same prefix** (In CMake single "find" script usually works with a single installation). On Linux, it is definitely the best way to install components of a single system into the same prefix. Probably, on Windows you should do the same.